# How to make sense of composing these two randomized functions?

Tags: haskell, monads

I am learning Haskell and currently reading up on Dan Piponi's blog on Monads  [here](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html). His first two examples make perfect sense to me. However I am not able to understand the third example, where he composes two randomized functions `f` and `g`:

```
f :: a -> StdGen -> (b,StdGen)
g :: a -> StdGen -> (b,StdGen)
```

My understanding is that the return type of `g` is `(b,StdGen)` but `f` takes two arguments of type `a` and `StdGen` respectively so `f` cannot be composed with `g`. However, a partially applied version `f x` can be composed with `g` if we unwrap the tuple returned by `g` and feed the second member of type `StdGen` to `f x`.

So,I think the the function `bind` should take the function `f x`:

```
 f x :: StdGen -> (b,StdGen)
```

and return a function `f'` whose input type is the same as the return type of `g`, i.e. `(b,StdGen)`:

```
f' :: (b,StdGen) -> (b,StdGen)
```

Bind should then look like:

```
bind :: (StdGen -> (b,StdGen)) -> ((b,StdGen) -> (b,StdGen))
```

But Dan defines `bind` as:

```
bind :: (a → StdGen → (b,StdGen)) → (StdGen → (a,StdGen)) → (StdGen → (b,StdGen))
```

From the comments on that post it is evident that many others were not able to follow Dan's line of reasoning initially. Dan gives an example too but the function `addDigit` does not use different types `a` and `b` but rather a common type `Int`.

Could someone describe what is the type of functions Dan is trying to compose and how he's arriving at the type of `bind` that he is using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of treating `f` as a two-argument function which returns a `(b, StdGen)`, you should treat `f` as a one-argument function which returns a `StdGen -> (b, StdGen)`. So consider that *whole type* `StdGen -> (b, StdGen)` as a single chunk/entity. If it helps, define yourself a type alias:

```
type Randomized a = StdGen -> (a, StdGen)
```

Now we can write

```
bind :: (a -> Randomized b) -> (Randomized a -> Randomized b)
```

and try to implement it. This type follows the pattern of the previous `bind` types: we take a function that takes a normal thing and returns a decorated thing, and turn it into a function that both takes and returns a decorated thing. (But again, the decoration is not just pairing with `StdGen` -- the decorated thing is itself a function.)

Similarly, the second exercise will be to implement

```
unit :: a -> Randomized a
```

which again follows the pattern set up in the previous exercises.

Comment: Oops, spoilers; he defines this type alias a bit later in the explanation (with a crazy `Randomised` spelling! people from outside my culture are weird). Still, different explanation orders work for different people, so maybe seeing this alias a bit earlier will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have no issues interpreting `f` and `g` as having types a -> Randomized b. However shouldn't `bind` then have the type `(a -> Randomized b) -> (Randomized b -> Randomized b)`  because bind should return a function that takes as input the output type of `g` which is `Randomized b` in this case.

Comment: @farhanhubble It is indeed possible to define monads in terms of composition of monadic functions; in this case, that would look like `compose :: (a -> Randomized b) -> (b -> Randomized c) -> (a -> Randomized c)`. The two ways of defining monads are equivalent -- you can define `bind` in terms of `compose` and `compose` in terms of `bind` (assuming you also have `unit` and `fmap` and the usual behavioral laws, of course). This tutorial just happens to be defining it in terms of `bind` instead of `compose` -- but this is mostly an aesthetic choice, not a technical one.

Comment: Daniel, my point is that with `bind` being defined as `bind :: (a -> Randomized b) -> (Randomized a -> Randomized b)`,  `bind f` will have the type `(Randomized a -> Randomized b)`. Now I don't see how we can do `(bind f).g` because `bind f` expects `Randomized a` as its input type but `g` has return type `Randomized b`.

Comment: @farhanhubble There's some ambiguity in your question, because you have given `f` and `g` very polymorphic types -- much more polymorphic than is realistically possible. So the question is uninteresting because we can't implement `f` or `g`. (But if we could, it would be easy to compose them -- since they are so polymorphic, the return type of the one will happily take on the argument type of the other.) (cont'd)

Comment: @farhanhubble On the other hand, suppose we make them a bit more monomorphic; let's say there are two fixed types `A` and `B`, and we give the type declaration `f, g :: A -> StdGen -> (B, StdGen)`. Now it's easier to implement `f` and `g`, but we have a different problem: `f` and `g` can't be composed together at all, because both of them return a `B` and neither of them take a `B`. So now the question is uninteresting for a different reason. (cont'd)

Comment: @farhanhubble There are several ways to make the question more reasonable. One natural way is to fix *three* types `A`, `B`, and `C`, and give the type declarations `f :: A -> StdGen -> (B, StdGen)` and `g :: B -> StdGen -> (C, StdGen)`. Then `f`'s output and `g`'s input look like they sort of match up, so there is a hope of composing them. In particular, `bind g . f` would typecheck given the type of `bind` from my answer.

Comment: The examples are from the blog I mentioned in the question and the polymorphic types `a` and `b` were one of the reason I was unable to grasp the example. From you comments I now understand that the goal is to go from `a->Randomized b` to `Randomized a -> Randomized b` and when `a` and `b` are suitable types we can indeed compose `bind f` with `g`. My confusion stemmed from the the use of two type variables `a` and `b` in this example as opposed to a single type variable `a` in the preceding two, where `bind` had the type `(a->m a) -> (ma -> ma)`.